# nav going below content on browser resize

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, responsive-design

I have a strange problem I can't figure out. I'm developing some navigation (that is responsive) independent from the rest of my site, and all is going well, except for one thing. If you load the page at a normal desktop size, the navigation is correctly above the placeholder image. But if you resize the browser window skinnier to where it switches to tablet size, and then resize it wider again, the navigation goes below the placeholder image.

Maybe it's something simple or maybe it's not. I can't figure it out.

My html structure is

```
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav></nav>
    <section id="content"></section>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

So I'm not sure how the content section is getting above the nav, but if you inspect the code and look at the html after doing the resize I describe above, the code becomes

```
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="content"></section>
    <nav></nav>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I'm not sure if it's the javascript I'm using or what the deal is that is juggling that and not resetting it. Surely it's not a missing CSS declaration...

**EDIT: Resolved! Thanks Chris!**

Comment: "I'm not sure if it's the javascript I'm using or what" - it is. Disable javascript and it doesn't happen.  It looks like the javascript is moving `.content` above `nav` on smaller screens, and not moving it back. Please paste the JavaScript here.

Comment: The javascript is somehow removing the nav and then when it adds it back in it's being placed below the section tag.

Comment: Here's a link to the javascript. I'm not sure how to code it to put the <nav> back above the <section>.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the JavaScript, it's 3400+ lines of code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code beginning on line #2619, the `destroy` function expects there to be an element `#header`, which doesn't exist.  Add the element `#header` as the first element within your `#wrapper` and the issue will resolve.  I'm assuming this isn't your JavaScript, so I wouldn't recommending changing it; instead, adjust your markup to give it what it expects.

Comment: You're a genius (or I'm not observant) because you were exactly right. I had removed the code for the #header as I wasn't needed that and it wasn't part of the navigation--I didn't realize it referenced that ID. I added an empty div just after the wrapper and closed it. Gave it a new ID name, changed the javascript to reference that ID name, and it's all fixed! Now I can go back to focusing on the design and not the "why the heck doesn't this work?" You rule!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the navigation.js  line

```
a.elt.insertAfter("#content");
```

to

```
a.elt.insertAfter("#header");
```

Comment: This may have worked. I didn't try it so I'm not sure! I was working on Chris's suggestion, got a phone call, finished his suggestion, tested it, and came back here to say that it worked. I just now saw your reply; sorry. Thanks for taking the time to help me! I appreciate it!